# In Django, how does one determine whether a business logic regarding user inputs goes into to model or form?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-validation

I always have the the trouble in determining whether I should put business logic regarding user inputs in model or form, especially for simple business rules. Say I have a *Product* class, and a business rule is that its *price* (an attribute of *Product*) cannot exceed $1000. Do I put the validation at the model or the form level? What are the criteria you use to determine such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can it *never* go above $1000? Then put the validation in the model.

A reason to put the validation in the form is if you want your users to enter a price below $1000 most of the time, but occasionally an administrator may enter a higher price through a different view.

Comment: Thanks Alasdair. What's your approach in adding model validation? What I would do is put the validation in Model.clean() and capture the pre_save signal, so that the clean() gets called whenever an instance of the Model gets saved. Is that what you would do?

Comment: I tend to rely on the fact that model forms (and therefore the Django admin) will call the model's clean method as part of their validation.  That does mean I have to remember to call `full_clean` before saving when I modify an instance manually. Using the `pre_save` signal is an interesting idea -- it might mean that the instance is cleaned twice when you use a model form.

Comment: Good point on the redundant clean calls. And thanks for sharing your approach in dealing with the said situation.

Comment: Alasdair, so under what circumstances, would you put business logic in forms? Example? Thanks.

Comment: Oops. There was a typo in my original answer. Say regular users cannot enter a price above $1000, but administrators can. Then you show them two different forms, each form with its own validation.

Comment: Ah~ that makes more sense now :) Thx